# Metodo de Gauss en Dev C++

Tags: c

Estoy iniciando y decidí realizar el método de Gauss en Dev++ pero al compilarlo los resultados no me dan, ¿alguien sabrá cual es el error?.

Lo que sucede es que cuando corro el programa (eso si lo hace bien) logro meter los datos de la matriz sin ningún problema pero al momento de que el programa captura los datos la primer columna sale en ceros y los resultados finales terminan siendo negativos y con valores indefinidos después del punto.

```c
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <math.h> 

void gotoxy(int x,int y){  
    HANDLE hcon;  
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  
    COORD dwPos;  
    dwPos.X = x;  
    dwPos.Y= y;  
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);  
}

void ceros(); 
void enc();
void captura(); 
void impresion(); 
void gauss();
void resultados(); 
int a[10][10];
float b[10][10];
float suma, resul[10], cero;
int i,j,k,m,n,z;

int main()
{
    ceros();
    enc(); 
    captura(); 
    impresion(); 
    gauss(); 
    resultados();
    gotoxy(20, 23),
    printf("Teclee <enter> para continuar");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void ceros()
{
    for(i=1;i<=9;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=9;j++){
            a[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

void enc()
{
    gotoxy(30,2);
    printf("METODO DE GAUSS");
    gotoxy(10,5);
    printf("Teclee num. de ecuaciones: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    n=m+1;
}

void captura()
{
    int lin,col; 
    col=10; lin=6; 
    gotoxy(col,lin);
    printf("captura de Coeficientes del sistema de ecuaciones");
    lin++;
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            gotoxy(col, lin);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            b[i][j]=(float)a[i][j];
            col=col+5;
        }
        col=10;lin=lin+1;
    }
}
```

Hasta aqui quiero creer que el codigo va bien pues la captura como menciono si la realiza

```c
void impresion()
{
    printf("\n SISTEMA DE ECUAIONES CAPTURADO\n\n");
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if (j==1){
                if(b[i][j]=0) printf(" "); 
                printf("%.0fX%d ",b[i][j],j);
            } 
            else
            {
                if(j==n){
                    printf(" =");
                    if(b[i][j]==0) printf(" "); 
                    printf("%.0f\n",b[i][j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (b[i][j]>=0){
                        printf("+%.0fX%d",b[i][j],j);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        printf(" %.0fX%d",b[i][j],j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void gauss()
{
    float p,cero, suma; 
    for (i=1;i<=m;i++){ 
        p=b[i][i];
        for (z=1;z<=n;z++){ 
            b[i][z]=b[i][z]/p;
        }
    
        for (k=1;k<=m; k++){
            if(k>1) {
                cero=b[k][i];
                for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
                    b[k][j]=b[k][j]-cero*b[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    suma=0.0; 
    resul[m]=b[m][n];
    for (i=1;i<=m-1;i++){
        j=m-i;
        k=j+1;
        for (k=j;k<=m; k++){
            suma=suma+b[j][k]*resul[k];
        }
        resul[j]=b[j][n]-suma;
        suma=0.0;
    }
}

void resultados()
{
    printf("\n\n El valor encontrado de las incognitas es: \n"); 
    for (i=1;i<=m;i++){
        printf("X%d=%.4f\n",i,resul[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te faltó un igual. `if(b[i][j] == 0) printf(" "); `

Comment: Por cierto, `int a[10][10];` está demás ya que no haces ningún cálculo sobre esa variable. Podría ser una variable normal `int a;` y `scanf("%d", &a); b[i][j] = a;`. O mejor aún, eliminas la variable `a` y de paso escaneas números con decimales `scanf("%f", &b[i][j]);`.